# SetIntervals in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, settimeout, setinterval

when a data is Changed , we use SetInterval to get data after *time , by which our page is not reloading and we get updated data after every given Seconds , but when we use to sign up, sign in & logout how do we Authenticate without reloading the page in our React Web App

Comment: Hello!
Please provide more information about your problem e.g. code example and detailed explanation.

Comment: sir when i Login , i save user id in localStorage , to conditionally render user to the home page i need to render conditionally after login  wheather the userid is present in the localstorage/not , to check that i've to use  navigate(0) // how to counter this without reloading the page

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet? Is there an issue with what you've tried? We can't address issues in code we can't see, so please [edit] to include a [mcve] and a description what the issue is that you face. If you are asking *how* to do this, then this is a too-broad question and the focus would need to be narrowed to a more specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment;

> sir when i Login , i save user id in localStorage , to conditionally render user to the home page i need to render conditionally after login wheather the userid is present in the localstorage/not , to check that i've to use navigate(0) // how to counter this without reloading the page

Which seems like you need to research more about authentication process. You **CAN'T** save critical data in localStorage, because anyone can reach and see localStorage.

You need a database, which lives in a server, and you do this authentication process via this server.

setInterval and localStorage are the worst choices to handle an authentication process. Even if it's not about authentication, I don't remember I have to use setInterval at any point though. Seems like there is something wrong either with your ReactJS knowledge or algorithm.

Also, ReactJS follows **Single Source of Truth** principle, if you keep important variables in localStorage, at some point you will face with tons of bugs becase you are   violating this principle.

Comment: yes sir I totally agree with you ,as a begineer i got this questtion : how do i verify my userid&&password Authentication from the server after click on login without making the page  reload , can you show me an example of your Professional code from login and Redirection to Home Page after Login, Thankyou For your valuable time

Comment: Hello, your question is too broad. There are tons of ways to authenticate, my advice would be take some lessons from Udemy or watch videos on YouTube and learn about them.